# How to check all elements in an array in pascal

Tags: arrays, pascal, freepascal

How would I code this so that if an element equals a certain value it would display a message, but if ALL elements inside that array aren't equal to that value, then it would output 'None'?

I've tried

```
for i := 0 to high(array) do
begin
    if (array[i].arrayElement = value) then
    begin
        WriteLn('A message');
    end;
end;
```

That bit works, but I don't know how to do the check all bit. I had this:

```
if (array[i].arrayElement to array[high(array)].arrayElement <> value) then
begin
    WriteLn('None');
end;
```

But it didn't allow me to use "to"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's clearest to write a helper function for this:

```
function ArrayContains(const arr: array of Integer; const value: Integer): Boolean;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := Low(arr) to High(arr) do
    if arr[i] = value then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Exit;
    end;
  Result := False;
end;
```

Or using `for/in`:

```
function ArrayContains(const arr: array of Integer; const value: Integer): Boolean;
var
  item: Integer;
begin
  for item in arr do
    if item = value then
    begin
      Result := True;
      Exit;
    end;
  Result := False;
end;
```

Then you call it like this:

```
if not ArrayContains(myArray, myValue) then
  Writeln('value not found');
```

Comment: (current versions of FPC support for..in)

Comment: That's probably the most useful news I learned from a comment!  Thanks.